# Can't use returned data in .ajax method of jQuery anywhere but the function itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

Rather odd problem in that I cannot use the data variable (the information returned by the ajax call) anywhere but in the .ajax function itself.

I am sure this is an issue of scope, however it is one that is beyond me and would be grateful of any pointers.

```
$('img#test').live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var test = getPreviewImage();
    alert(test); // This just gives undefined
});


function getPreviewImage()
{
  var output;

  var img_bg = $('div#preview-1 img:nth-child(1)').prop('src');
  var img_fg = $('div#preview-1 img:nth-child(2)').prop('src');


  $.ajax({
    url: "/blah.php?v=12345,

  }).done(function (data) {

    alert(data); // This gives the correct response
    output = data; // This should take the data value but still be in scope for the return statement below

  });

return output;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't really a problem of scope but of synchronicity.

When your `getPreviewImage` function returns, the ajax call hasn't yet be made (it's asynchronous and the execution flow doesn't wait for the request and response to be complete), so `output` is still null.

You can solve this by making a synchronous ajax call or by providing a callback to `getPreviewImage` instead of using its return value.

To make a synchronous ajax call, pass `false` as the `async` parameter. See [the doc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

To use a callback, you can do this :

```
$('img#test').live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    getPreviewImage(function(test){
        // use test
    });
});


function getPreviewImage(callback) {

  $.ajax({
    url: "/blah.php?v=12345",...

  }).done(function (data) {
    callback(data);
  });
}
```

Using a synchronous call is easier (you just have to set a parameter to false) but the callback logic is generally preferable as it doesn't block your script and allows parallel requests.

Comment: Have just now understood how your example works. Nice work, has well illustrated a new JS concept for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can call another function using the `$.ajax` jQuery function.  Try doing the following.

```
function getPreviewImage()
{
  var output;

  var img_bg = $('div#preview-1 img:nth-child(1)').prop('src');
  var img_fg = $('div#preview-1 img:nth-child(2)').prop('src');


  $.ajax({
    url: "/blah.php?v=12345,

  }).done(someotherFunction)

  });

}

function someotherFunction(data) {
     return data;
}
```