# How can I store an AJAX call's data in a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can’t use returned data in .ajax method of jQuery anywhere but the function itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11247066/cant-use-returned-data-in-ajax-method-of-jquery-anywhere-but-the-function-itse)

I'm trying to store an AJAX call's return value into a variable.

```
var getJSONData = function(){
    JSONData = $.getJSON('/api');
};

var reloadPage = function(json_data){
    //Do some DOM manipulation with the JSON data
    //console.log(json_data) returns undefined
};

reloadPage(getJSONData());
```

This code doesn't work. The api works though when I access it directly or using the following code

```
$.getJSON('/api', function(data){console.log(data)});
```

This works and gets me the JSON data I wanted.

Any idea how I could make it work ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about

```
var getJSONData = function(callback){
    JSONData = $.getJSON('/api', callback);
};

var reloadPage = function(json_data){
    //Do some DOM manipulation with the JSON data
    //console.log(json_data) returns undefined
};

getJSONData(reloadPage);
```

Comment: Thanks, it does work !

I can see how it would turn as a large pile of callback spaghetti after a while though.

Answer (score 3):

AJAX stands for **Asynchronous** JavaScript and XML. Your data is not immediately available at the moment you execute an AJAX call, so that's why you need to use callback functions to react to the later response.

jQuery AJAX calls provides [Deferred Objects](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) that you can use.

```
var getJSONData = function(){
    return $.getJSON('/api');
};

var reloadPage = function(data){
    console.log(data);
};

getJSONData().done(reloadPage);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into deferred objects.

Answer (score 2):

`$.getJSON` doesn't return the JSON but a promise.

The simplest is to use it like this :

```
 $.getJSON('/api', reloadPage);
```

Your `reloadPage` function will be called with the JSON data as argument when the response will be received by the browser.

Answer (score 2):

`$.getJSON()` is asynchronuous. It is accessible via a callback:

```
var getJSONData = function(callback){
    $.getJSON('/api').success(data) {
       callback(data);
    };
};

var reloadPage = function(){
    getJSONData(function(json_data) {
    //Do some DOM manipulation with the JSON data
    //console.log(json_data) returns undefined
    });
};

reloadPage();
```